# T-SQL Percentage of 2 summed fields Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I'm currently trying to return the percentage of 2 summed fields. The code I've tried looks as follows:

```
CAST(
    COUNT(et.NotEnrolled) + 
    COUNT((etne.EmployeeID)) * 100.0 / Count(et.EmployeeID) 
    as numeric (10,2)) as 'Not Enrolled %'
```

The counts for each field are:

```
et.NotEnrolled = 151
etne.EmployeeID = 707
```

My answer should be 21.36 and yet I'm getting 128.68 as my answer. Any suggestions or obvious flaws in my code?

Comment: x+y/z = x + (y/z). You need (x+y)/z if you want the addition to happen first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an issue with your parenthesis.

I guess it should be like:

```
CAST((COUNT(et.NotEnrolled)+COUNT(etne.EmployeeID))*100.0/Count(et.EmployeeID) as numeric (10,2)) as 'Not Enrolled %'
```

Comment: It was the case that the parenthesis were executing in a unwanted order. But your solution worked. Thanks.